# What is the difference between "this IEnumerable<T> items" and "this T items"?

Tags: c#, generics

I am confused in choosing the following.

```
public static Foo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
            where T : XYZ

public static Foo<T>(this T items)
       where T : IEnumerable<XYZ>
```

What is the difference between them? I don't find any difference so far.

`XYZ` is an abstract class.

Comment: Your second example requires a second type parameter: `Foo<T, XYZ>`

Comment: @silkfire: I don't think so. It works without a second type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First example method is an extension method for an instance of class that inherits or is `IEnumerable<XYZ>` and where T (generic, e.g. `.Foo<XYZ>`) inherits `XYZ`.

Second method is for an instance of class that inherits or is T and where T inherits `IEnumerable<XYZ>`.

So, what is the **difference**? First method accepts an `IEnumerable` with instances of a type that inherits `XYZ`. Second method accepts an `IEnumerable` with only instances of type `XYZ`.